# Why does "a".search(".") return 0 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, methods

Why does `"a".search(".")` return `0` in JavaScript, even though `"".search(".")` returns `-1`? Does `"."` have a special meaning when used in `search()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search):

> The **`search()`** method executes a search for a match between a regular expression and this [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) object.
>
> ⋮
>
> If a non-RegExp object `regexp` is passed, it is implicitly converted to a RegExp with `new RegExp(regexp)`.

That happens in this case, and `"."` gets converted to `/./`.

`.` does have special meaning in JavaScript regular expressions: it matches any non-newline character. `"a"` has a non-newline character at position 0, and `""` has no non-newline characters to match.

You might have been thinking of [`String.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), which searches for a string.

```js
console.log("a".indexOf("."));
```

Comment: Welp, I had no idea what "implicitly" meant there but I guess I do now. By the way, is `search()` the only method "implicitly" convert its argument to a regular expression? Or do I have to watch out for any other one that takes strings too?

Comment: @Vun-HughVaw: I think that’s the only one.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because `.search()` takes regular expression as parameter. And in case you pass a string, it is converted to regular expression implicitly. However, when you talk about ".", on changing it to regular expression, it can become `/./` but it needs to be `/\./`. That is why, you would have to pass a regular expression in place of a string for ".".

**Do it like :** `"a".search(/\./);`

Answer (score 0):

search() method returns the index of the first match, or -1 if no match was found.

```js
console.log("asd".search("d")); // 2

console.log("aasds.asdd".search(/\./)); // 5
```

The correct syntax to match a dot is by a regex with escape character `\.`

Answer (score 0):

`.` matches any character except for line terminators.
Therefore, `"a".search(".")` returns 0.

matches `a` at `0` index.

Answer (score 0):

For your query, `.` has special meaning in `regex` expression. `search()` uses `regex` in back. So, you have to put `escape` character before special character like,

```js
console.log( "".search("\\.") );
```